# dismissing uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Ok, I really spend 2 days on this and it has gotten me stumped.

From my main UIViewController I called a WebViewController which is a UIViewController with a UIWebView inside:

```
UOLCategoriesWebViewController *ucwvcontroller = [[UOLCategoriesWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UOLCategoriesWebViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:ucwvcontroller animated:YES];
    [ucwvcontroller release];
```

Inside the UOLCategoriesWebViewController I've call the delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` where when the user clicks on a particular type of link it parses out the params and return back to the main UIViewController (or at least that's what I want it to do):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    BOOL continueOrExit = YES;
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = [url relativeString];
    NSString *urlParams = [url query];
    NSArray *urlParamArr = [urlParams componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSLog(@"the url is: %@",urlString);
    //NSLog(@"the params are: %@,%@",[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:0],[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:1]);

    //BOOL endTrain1 = [[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:1] hasPrefix:@"subCatValue"];
    //BOOL endTrain2 = ([urlParamArr objectAtIndex:1
    //NSLog(@"Number of elements: %@",[urlParamArr count]);
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Enter into His glory");

        if ([urlString hasSuffix:@"categories_list.php"]) {

            //NSLog(@"2nd Heaven");
            continueOrExit = YES;

        }else if ([[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:1] hasPrefix:@"subCatValue"]) {
            continueOrExit = NO;
            NSLog(@"end of the train");
            NSArray *firstParamStringArr = [[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSArray *secondParamStringArr = [[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString *catSelected = [firstParamStringArr objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *subCatSelected = [secondParamStringArr objectAtIndex:1];



            //go back to native app
            [self goBackToMain:catSelected andSubCat:subCatSelected];



        }
    }
    return continueOrExit;
}
```

Actually in the above function where I am calling the `goBackToMain` method I want it to call the delegate method and return to the mainviewcontroller. Unfortunately after executing that `goBackToMain` method it goes back to this method and continue to return continueOrExit.

Is there anyway to make it truly exit without returning anything? I've tried putting in multiple returns to no avail. Or can I in the html page pass some javascript to directly call this method so that I don't have to go through this delegate method?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what exactly you are doing. if the url suffix is categories_list.php you want it to load and if not you want to do some stuff and then dismiss?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct :)

Comment: what do you mean by exit without returning anything...I am not getting your exact purpose...

Comment: I just want when the user click on that type of link, the UIWebView can be dismissed and the delegate method called from the UIViewController that originally created this uiwebview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to defer the invocation of `goBackToMain:andSubCat:` after the delegate method execution. This way, the delegate method can return and the invocation is then processed:

```
NSArray *firstParamStringArr = [[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSArray *secondParamStringArr = [[urlParamArr objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *catSelected = [firstParamStringArr objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *subCatSelected = [secondParamStringArr objectAtIndex:1];

NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(goBackToMain:andSubCat:)];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[inv retainArguments];
[inv setTarget:self];
[inv setSelector:selector];
[inv setArgument:&catSelected atIndex:2];
[inv setArgument:&subCatSelected atIndex:3];
[inv performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```